# PHP form works locally but not on Heroku

Tags: php, forms, git, heroku

I recently deployed a basic php form on Heroku that inserts inputs into a database.  When testing the code locally, using a local database/connection, the code works as intended.

When trying to run the code on Heroku, the php script called as "action" in my form tag doesn't seem to produce any results.  I am unable to echo any type of output whatsoever to the page, and as such I can't print the results of my DB connection to see if that is the problem, although because it works locally, I don't think that this is the case.

I have seen in other posts on this issue sometimes it was a matter of merging branches via git; I have been solely pushing using 'git push heroku master', and don't think that this is the issue.  Any ideas as to what my problem may be are much appreciated.

PS: the images of my form, stored in an "assets" folder, don't display on Heroku as well, but it seems like this may be due to Heroku requiring a different path. Any advice on this issue would be great as well.

edit: I have checked the current version on heroku using heroku releases; it is the correct code

Comment: Please use the [`heroku releases`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases#listing-release-history) command to verify that you have the correct revision deployed to Heroku.